# Error running process with Symfony on php server

Tags: php, laravel, serve

I developed an API in php with washable to run an algorithm in C ++ with opencv. The application sends a photo to the server, which in turn starts an .exe file responsible for processing this image. When executing the file via terminal, the algorithm correctly processes the image. However, to perform this processing via code in the API I am using Symfony, more precisely Process. Well, when executing the line below it always returns to me that the .exe file was not found.

```
$process = new Process(['feridas/exec', 'final.png']);
```

I have also tried in the following ways, but without success.

```
$process = new Process(['./exec', 'final.png']);
$process = new Process(['server-laravel/resources/feridas/exec']);
```

Code complete:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

class ClassificationController extends Controller
{

public function process(Request $request)
{
    /** @var $image UploadedFile*/
    $image = $request->files->get('image');
    if (empty($image)) {
        throw new \Exception("Arquivo não fornecido.");
    }

    $validExtensions = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg'];

    if (!in_array($image->getMimeType(), $validExtensions)) {
        dd($image->getMimeType());
        throw new \Exception("Arquivo não suportado");

    }

    if (!$image->move(resource_path('feridas'), $image->getClientOriginalName())) {
        throw new \Exception("Error moving file.");
    }

    $newPath = resource_path('feridas/' . $image->getClientOriginalName());

    return $this->processImage($newPath);
}

private function processImage($newPath){
    $process = new Process(['ls', '-la', resource_path('feridas')]);

    $process->run();
    $process->wait();
    

    if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
        return [
            'success' => true, //ou false
            'message'    => 'Could not execute script: %s', $process->getErrorOutput()
        ];
        throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
    }

    $output = $process->getOutput();
    return [
        'success' => true, //ou false
        'message'    => $output
    ];
 
}
}
```

outuput:

[image]

When executing the same algorithm via terminal, it correctly returns the output, time of execution of the algorithm in seconds.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using ```resource_path('feridas/exec')``` as the path? Assuming that there is an "exec" file in this folder.

Comment: Enrico, return error 500

Comment: evaluate the directories, like `var_dump(__DIR__, realpath('.'), realpath('feridas/exec'))`... you're using a relative path which doesn't resolve to the path you're expecting. edit: forgot the cwd.. `var_dump(getcwd())`

Comment: I changed the code according to your answer: `var_dump(__DIR__, realpath('.'), realpath('feridas/exec'));
        $process = new Process([var_dump(getcwd())]);` "sh: 1: exec: : Permission denied\n"

Comment: I already gave permission chmod -R 777 and when sending the image the permission is changed.

Comment: I asked a new question now with the new error I'm having. Can you help me please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65483579/full-file-permission-is-changed-when-uploading-file-to-my-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no cwd argument value in the Process class, getpwd() the current path of php.

Laravel is the path to the entry point, `public/index.php`.

```php
var_dump(getcwd());

// /home/user/public
```

So it is clear to define the absolute path where the file exists.

```php
var_dump(resource_path('feridas/exec'));

// /home/user/resources/feridas/exec
```

Try it.

```php
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$process = new Process([resource_path('feridas/exec'), resource_path('feridas/final.png')]);

$process->run(function ($type, $buffer) {
    if (Process::ERR === $type) {
        echo 'ERR > '.$buffer;
    } else {
        echo 'OUT > '.$buffer;
    } 
});
```

If that doesn't work, please let us know the next result.

```php
$process = new Process(['ls', '-la', resource_path('feridas/exec'), resource_path('feridas/final.png')]);
```

```php
$process = new Process(['ls', '-la', resource_path('feridas/exec'), $newPath]);
```

```sh
// SSH Terminal

[root@dev ~]# /home/user/resources/feridas/exec /home/user/resources/feridas/final.png

[root@dev ~]# ls -la /home/user/resources/feridas/exec /home/user/resources/feridas/final.png
```

---

Symfony process doc - https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#getting-real-time-process-output

---

#### Answers to the results of further execution.

[image]

Enter the directory to be moved in the second argument, `$cwd`.

```php
//$process = new Process(['ls', '-la', resource_path('feridas')]);
$process = new Process(['./exec'], resource_path('feridas'));


// arguments
// $command = ['./exec']
// $cwd = resource_path('feridas')
```

Check the class arguments - https://github.com/symfony/process/blob/5.x/Process.php#L141

```php
public function __construct(array $command, string $cwd = null, array $env = null, $input = null, ?float $timeout = 60)
```

Comment: Been, I changed the code as you suggested, updated in the question, however the algorithm did not execute with the image. On exit it does not show the execution time of the algorithm, as it appears when executing it via terminal, seen in the updated question.

Comment: I added...  `Answers to the results of further execution.`

Comment: thank you very much, it finally worked correctly