# Full file permission is changed when uploading file to my API

Tags: php, android, laravel, server

I am developing an application that sends images to be processed on the server. The server receives the captured image in the application and processes the image using opencv. Both the server and the application are already working and there is communication between both. The project folder, inside the server, already has all the permissions granted as shown in the image below. The problem is that when sending the application image, containing the default name 'final.png' for all images received on the server, permission is changed on the server side and, with this, the server cannot perform the processing and consequently the change in the image, as you no longer have the necessary permissions. Can anyone tell me why the image changes permissions when it is sent to the server, or how to resolve to grant all permissions again before the image is processed? I'm using the laravel framework for server development and my application is on native android.

directory of the algorithm to be processed the image, where the 'exec' is the algorithm that processes and the respective image.

[image]

Response API to send image:

[image]

After the image is sent to the server:

[image]

My code server:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

class ClassificationController extends Controller
{

public function process(Request $request)
{
    /** @var $image UploadedFile*/
    $image = $request->files->get('image');
    if (empty($image)) {
        throw new \Exception("Arquivo não fornecido.");
    }

    $validExtensions = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg'];

    if (!in_array($image->getMimeType(), $validExtensions)) {
        dd($image->getMimeType());
        throw new \Exception("Arquivo não suportado");

    }

    if (!$image->move(resource_path('feridas'), $image->getClientOriginalName())) {
        throw new \Exception("Error moving file.");
    }

    $newPath = resource_path('feridas/' . $image->getClientOriginalName());

    return $this->processImage($newPath);
}

private function processImage($newPath)
{
    var_dump(__DIR__, realpath('.'), realpath('feridas/exec'));
    $process = new Process([var_dump(getcwd())]);
    $process->run();
    $process->wait();
    

    if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
        return [
            'success' => true, //ou false
            'message'    => 'Could not execute script: %s', $process->getErrorOutput()
        ];
        throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
    }

    $output = $process->getOutput();
    $result = json_decode($output, true);
    if (null === $result) {
        return [
            'success' => true, //ou false
            'message'    => 'Could not decode return value from script from template "%s" (should be a JSON encoded string): %s', $output
        ];
    }
 
    else{
        return [
            'success' => true, //ou false
            'message'    => "WORK"
        ];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I did not read your post. Saw the subject only. I'm not amazed that on your server the permissions are different from on the Android device.

Comment: `$process = new Process([var_dump(getcwd())]);` ???

Comment: Miken32, some problem?

Comment: @blackapps I know that the permissions are different between server and android, the question is why the permission is changed in the server side image?

Comment: Do not understand. If they are different then they are different. If they change then tell when and where they change.

Comment: so, I can't say when and why they change, I'm allowing all permissions on the project's root folder in my API, when uploading the image, for some reason the image permission is changed. But I don't know who makes this change, whether it's the OS, the server or something else.

Comment: @blackapps pointing out that I am sending the image via postman, regardless of the image it changes the permissions.

Comment: I can only repeat: `I'm not amazed that on your server the permissions are different from on the Android device. –` For the rest i still do not understand your problem.

Comment: So, what has been like android permissions with my server permissions, and at this moment of testing, I'm using the postman to send an image.